# EFI and SMC firmware updates - how to determine if the downloadable version is more recent?

Tags: macbook-pro, firmware

I have a 15-inch MacBook Pro late 2011. System Information gives me the following firmware versions:

**EFI Boot Rom Version**: MBP81.0047.B2C

**SMC Version (system)**:   1.69f3

Apple provides the following web site for downloading firmware upgrades: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518

On this website the following downloads are available for my system:

**EFI Boot ROM version**: MBP81.0047.2AB (2015-001)

**SMC version**: 1.69f3 (SMC 1.5)

The SMC version is the same as the one installed on my system, so no need to update anything.

However, there is a discrepancy with regard to the EFI Boot ROM versions (installed MBP81.0047.B2C vs. MBP81.0047.2AB). How can I tell whether the ...2AB version is a newer version than the ...B2C version on my system? Will the upgrade programme check during the upgrade process?  I

Comment: What version of the Mac OS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updater program will check to see if you already have the latest version of the Firmware.  Taken directly from the Apple web page that you linked to:

> If you try to use a manual updater that's not designed for your Mac,
>   or if it's not needed, the installer alerts you and the software isn't
>   installed